# Center one div and set one div to right inside a container

Tags: javascript, vue.js, tailwind-css

So i have a container that is flex, and I want to add 2 more div inside it so 1 is centered and one is on the right edge.
Can someone pls help. the container must be flex.

Comment: Welcome to [SO]. Please read [ask] and update your question accordingly. It's ***quite*** important. To put it into perspective, the chances of anyone helping you, considering the current form of your question, are minimal.

Comment: Please make some minimal effort if you expect any fast and efficient answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an empty `div` inside of parent container at the beginning so you can then use `justify-content: space-between` on the parent container. Check the code below:

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid green;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-between; /* Add this */
}

.child {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <!-- Empty DIV for the sake of justify-content: space-between -->
  <div></div>
  <div class="child">CENTER</div>
  <div class="child">RIGHT</div>
</div>
```